# How to blur all views in container laying "beneath" blurring view if container created programmatically?

Tags: android, canvas, view, blur

In project, that i am doing, i met with problem. I must create a View, based on xml, css, and assets, and manifest, describes relations.

I use Compositor pattern for parse xml, and creating Views hierarchy. Problem is in few views in hiererchy. They might have a parameter "blur" with boolean value and it can looks like:

```
RelativeLayout - container
|---ImageView - view in container with background image
|---RelativeLayout - less than container, bluring view
```

I use [great article](http://trickyandroid.com/advanced-blurring-techniques/) and create two methods

```
public static void applyBlur(final View parent, final View blurring) {
    parent.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            parent.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            parent.buildDrawingCache();

            Bitmap bmp = parent.getDrawingCache();

            blur(bmp, blurring);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

and

```
private static void blur(Bitmap bkg, View view) {

    float radius = 10;

    Bitmap overlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getLayoutParams().width, view.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlay);
    canvas.translate(-view.getLeft(), -view.getTop());
    canvas.drawBitmap(bkg, 0, 0, null);
    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(view.getContext());
    Allocation overlayAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(
            rs, overlay);
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(
            rs, overlayAlloc.getElement());
    blur.setInput(overlayAlloc);
    blur.setRadius(radius);
    blur.forEach(overlayAlloc);
    overlayAlloc.copyTo(overlay);
    view.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(view.getContext().getResources(), overlay));
    rs.destroy();
}
```

It works perfectly with layout created in xml - all views in hierarchy under blurring view are blur. But if I create view hierarchy programmatically i can blur only parent view, nor the views in same level of hierarhy with the blurring view. Looks like parent view "don't know" about other views in it.

For example when i remove image view from described hierarchy and set it's image as background for parent - I get result. But it is not the solution because hierarchy deeper, than i describe, and I must blur all views "beneath" blurring views. How can I "explain" to container that it contains all view that it contains? It must be possible, because i see how it works when layout created in xml in app resourses. Container "knows" about all views in it and all they are blurring perfectly in this case.

Answer (score 1):

@iamthevoid for views we have a property called Alpha. Try setting the property to imageview or relativelayout.

Comment: Alpha is the transparency. It is good, but not the effect which i need. I need the http://imgur.com/a/9rGLL . I made it for parent view if it created programmaticaly (you can see result at the picture) and for all views in layout if they created in resourses, but cannot achieve it for all views in layout if i make they programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this. Problem was in using Universal Image Loader library. It load image in imageView async and blurring "screenshot" under child relative layout is going before image shown in ImageView. It produces image aren't blurring. I excluded UIL from logic and load image in ImageView in UIThread for be sure than blur going strongly after image loading. And it works. )) Thanks